# Função createElement

Tags: php, javascript, html

Olhando o código abaixo tenho 3 botões com a função "conteudo()" certo? Essa função cria uma div na qual irá receber o valor do campo de texto que esta ao lado do botão. Quando eu clico em qualquer um dos botões ele sempre exibe o valor do "txt_1". Como eu faço para que cada botão imprima seu determinado campo de texto que esta ao lado?

```js
function conteudo() {
  //Cria a div
  var div_c = document.createElement("DIV");
  div_c.style.width = "30%";
  div_c.style.height = "35px";
  div_c.style.margin = "30px 10px";
  div_c.style.background = "#ffe0e0";
  div_c.innerHTML = "Item: <input name='txt_result' id='txt_result' type='text' value='' />";
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div_c);

  //Pega os conteúdos e exibe
  var num1 = document.getElementById('txt_1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('txt_2').value;
  var num3 = document.getElementById('txt_3').value;
  document.getElementById('txt_result').value = num1;
}
```

```html
<input name="txt_1" id="txt_1" type="text" value="Item1" /><input name="btn1" id="btn1" type="button" value="Botao 1" onclick="conteudo()" /><br />
<input name="txt_2" id="txt_2" type="text" value="Item2" /><input name="btn2" id="btn2" type="button" value="Botao 2" onclick="conteudo()" /><br />
<input name="txt_3" id="txt_3" type="text" value="Item3" /><input name="btn3" id="btn3" type="button" value="Botao 3" onclick="conteudo()" />

<div id="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens explicitamente `.value = num1;`, por isso o valor é sempre o mesmo.
Para corrigir isso deves usar o `. previousElementSibling` que vai dar-te o elemento anterior. Mas precisas também saber o elemento clicado, e isso consegues passando o `this` à função.

Por passos:

- usa `onclick="conteudo(this)"` para dar à função acesso ao elemento clicado
- usa `var num = btn.previousElementSibling.value;` para ir buscar o valor que procuras
- usa `div_c.querySelector('[name="txt_result"]').value = num;` para ir buscar o input que está dentro de `div_c` e setar o valor que recebeste do ponto anterior

Assim podes fazer o que queres desta maneira:

```js
function conteudo(btn) {
  //Cria a div
  var div_c = document.createElement("DIV");
  div_c.style.width = "30%";
  div_c.style.height = "35px";
  div_c.style.margin = "30px 10px";
  div_c.style.background = "#ffe0e0";
  div_c.innerHTML = "Item: <input name='txt_result'  type='text' value='' />";
  document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div_c);

  //Pega os conteúdos e exibe
  var num = btn.previousElementSibling.value;
  div_c.querySelector('[name="txt_result"]').value = num;
}
```

```html
<input name="txt_1" id="txt_1" type="text" value="Item1" /><input name="btn1" id="btn1" type="button" value="Botao 1" onclick="conteudo(this)" /><br />
<input name="txt_2" id="txt_2" type="text" value="Item2" /><input name="btn2" id="btn2" type="button" value="Botao 2" onclick="conteudo(this)" /><br />
<input name="txt_3" id="txt_3" type="text" value="Item3" /><input name="btn3" id="btn3" type="button" value="Botao 3" onclick="conteudo(this)" />

<div id="main"></div>
```

Repara que uso `div_c.querySelector('[name="txt_result"]')` e assim não estou dependente da `id` do input recém criado.